# How do I find out long time a service has been up and running for in CentOS 6?

Tags: centos-6

How do I find out how long has a service eg. nginx has been up and running for in CentOS 6?

In CentOS 7, I can use `systemctl status nginx` and it shows how long did the service last started.

But in CentOS 6, the equivalent command `service nginx status` only gives me the PID and saying nginx is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ps -p ProcessID -o etime=` will give you running time for process you are looking for.
Replace *ProcessID* with actual one or use `pidof` to find `nginx` automatically:

`ps -p $(pidof -s nginx) -o etime=`

Output format: " Days-Hours:Mins:Secs"

---

If you need running time in seconds then :

`ps -p $(pidof -s nginx) -o etimes=`

but be noted, while `etime` is POSIX standard, `etimes` can be found only on recent linux distributions

---

Output in human readable format :

```
#!/bin/sh

Service='sshd'

PID=$(pidof -s ${Service} )
[ -z ${PID} ] && { echo "${Service} not running."; exit 1; }

rt=$(ps -p ${PID} -o etime=) ;  echo "${rt}";
[ -z "$(echo "${rt}" | grep '-')" ] && days=0 || {
  days=$(echo ${rt} | awk -F- '{print $1}')
}

ft=$(echo "${rt}" | grep -o ':' | awk 'BEGIN{RS=""; OFS="";}  {print length }' )
[ ${ft} -eq 1 ] && hours=0 || {
  hours=$(echo ${rt} | awk -F\: '{print $1}' | sed 's/[0-9]-//g')
}
[ ${ft} -eq 1 ] && {
  mins=$(echo ${rt} | awk -F\: '{print $1}')
} || {
  mins=$(echo ${rt} | awk -F\: '{print $2}' | sed 's/\:.*$//g')
}
[ ${ft} -eq 1 ] && {
  secs=$(echo ${rt} | awk -F\: '{print $2}')
} || {
  secs=$(echo ${rt} | awk -F\: '{print $3}')
}

echo "${Service} running: ${days} days, ${hours} hours, ${mins} minutes, ${secs} seconds."
```

Comment: `etime=` words, but not `etimes=`, I got `ERROR: Unknown user-defined format specifier "etimes".`

Comment: When executing the first command, it shows `4-15:59:43`, what does `4-` represent?  Is it possible to format it to show something more human readable such as the result from `uptime`?  eg. 3 days, 72 hours, 4320 minutes, etc?

Comment: `etimes=` works in CentOS 7, but not CentOS 6

Comment: @KDX `4-` represent - days. I updated my answer with output you asked. `etime` is POSIX standard and `etimes` is available only on recent linux distributions